# How to remove function from list in R?

Tags: r, list, nonatomic

I have list with two functions:

```
foo <- function() { print('foo') }
bar <- function() {}
l <- list(foo, bar)
```

How can I remove function foo without knowing its index?

I've tried this (to get indexes for sub setting):

```
> which(l == foo)
Error in l == foo : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Is there easy way to remove non-atomic from list without looping?

Comment: I think you should use `identical` for this purpose : `identical(l[[1]], foo)`

Comment: An idea that searches for `foo` in a function's body: `Filter(function(x) !any(grepl("foo", body(x))),l)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the code in the question, use `identical` we can get its index like this:

```
Position(function(fun) identical(fun, foo), l)
## [1] 1
```

or

```
which(sapply(l, identical, foo))
## [1] 1
```

If you know something about the functions you may be able to run them and select based on the output.  For the example this works:

```
Position(function(f) length(f()), l)
## [1] 1
```

If you have control over the creation of the list an easy approach is to create the list with names:

```
l2 <- list(foo = foo, bar = bar)
nms <- setdiff(names(l2), "foo")
```

### Removal

If we know that `foo` is in `l` once then

```
l[-ix]
```

or in the case of `l2`:

```
l2[nms]
```

or use the alternative given by @Gregor:

```
Filter(function(x) !identical(x, foo), l)
```

### Edge cases

If `foo` might not be in `l` you will need to check that condition first. `Position` and `match` return `NA` if there is no match (or specify the `nomatch` argument to either) and `which` returns `intetger(0)` for a no match.

If `foo` can be in `l` more than once then use the `which` alternative above.

### Other

Note that `which` and `Filter` check every position but `match` and `Position` stop after the first match.

Comment: All at once: `Filter(function(x) !identical(x, foo), l)`